# How to preload Ionic components in v5

Tags: ionic-framework

We have an Ionic5-Angular app that is also being deployed as a web app. It’s nice that Ionic lazy loads all of its components - it greatly reduces the bundle size. However, we’re running into issues when it comes to user interactions that trigger lazy-loaded components.

As an example, we have a button that triggers a Dialog. When deployed, there is a noticeable delay between tapping the button and the dialog being displayed. When tested on a slow 2G internet connection, it took nearly a minute for the dialog to display. Once it has loaded once everything is fine but we are finding that the more impatient users are tapping the button several times because it looks broken.

I want the web browser to download the Ionic component together in advance while downloading the web page not when it’s requested.

Comment: Hope this could help! [Custom preloading strategy for angular modules](https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/custom-preloading-strategy-for-angular-modules-b3b5c873681a)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can preload individual components, but you can preload modules. Use Angular's [PreloadAllModules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading) like this:

```js
import { RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

...

RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```